# is there a way to sum the amount of numbers in a list

Tags: python, sum

if i have a list with some numbers that the user was input to the function, how can i return exept the list of his numbers, the sum of them also? (i maen the sum of the values and not the sum of how many numbers are in the list.

```
def input_list():

    EMPTHYֹֹ_NUM = ""
    my_list = []
    user_num_string = input()
    while True:
        if user_num_string != EMPTHYֹֹ_NUM:
            my_list.append(user_num_string)
            user_num_string = input()
        elif user_num_string == EMPTHYֹֹ_NUM:
            return my_list

print(input_list())
```

i expected the output of `[num1, num1, num1 + num2]`

but i got only `[num1, num2]`

Comment: where is the `num1 + num2` expected to come from?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?x = [2, 3, 4]
c = sum(x)
x.append(c) : o/p: [2, 3, 4, 9]

Comment: append to a list means you are adding an element to the end of that list. It is not adding the elements of the list. you need to add them using sum or +

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `int()` to convert the input strings into `int`s.  Then you can just use the `sum` function to get the sum of the list values and append it to the result.

```
def input_list():
    my_list = []
    while True:
        user_num_string = input()
        if not user_num_string:
            return my_list + [sum(my_list)]
        my_list.append(int(user_num_string))

print(input_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script you could use

```
def input_list():

    EMPTYֹֹ_NUM = ""
    my_list = []
    user_num_string = input()
    sum =0
    while True:
        if user_num_string != EMPTYֹֹ_NUM:
            my_list.append(user_num_string)
            sum+= int(user_num_string)
            user_num_string = input()
        elif user_num_string == EMPTYֹֹ_NUM:
            my_list.append(sum)
            return my_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(input_list())
```

Comment: @SpoonMeiser He calculates it and appends it inside the list before returning the list.